# Adding Child View in a Layout Programatically

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to add view in GridLayout(3 columns) in horizontal manner but child view width is unspecified, sometime it has very broad width. Because of it third element goes out of view width.

I want to know if there is any layout or any way to make it done.

[image: Screenshot]

```
<GridLayout
                android:id="@+id/activity_detailed_view_gl_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:columnCount="3"
                android:layout_gravity="start|top"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

Comment: Did you try to add `android:numColumns="3"` & `android:layout_width="match_parent"` in your gridview? Can you post the code for the xml file? That would be better..

Comment: please provide some code that you are already using.

Comment: @baymaxx see my xml code (It is GridLayout not GridView).

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason for using Grid Layout ? You can use Linear Layout with orientation Horizontal

Comment: I want to add view programatically and if row one become full, view should add on row two.

Comment: try layout_marginRight  with value 16dp